# python dictionaries: assigning a blank dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Why does the following code give the following error and how do i assign it to blank dictionary within the function:

```
import time 

dictionary_power_readings = {}

def update_dict():
    ApparentPower = "power"
    dictionary_power_readings[time.time()] = ApparentPower
    print(dictionary_power_readings)
    dictionary_power_readings ={} 




while True:
    update_dict()
    time.sleep(1)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "updating_dict_from_function.py", line 15, in 
> update_dict()   File "updating_dict_from_function.py", line 7, in update_dict
> dictionary_power_readings[time.time()] = ApparentPower UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dictionary_power_readings'
> referenced before assignment

Comment: `global dictionary_power_readings` inside the function

Comment: either use `global` as mentioned in comment above, or even better: pass the dictionary into the function as a parameter. The code will be easier to test, extend and read.

Comment: @rdas and @yedpodtrzitko's answers are correct. But I wonder what is the purpose of this code and `dictionary_power_readings`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I simplified the problem for stack overflow so the objective of the code probably doesn't make sense to you.  In summary, I'm processing data im receiving from a MQTT broker and will be running a machine learning model on the data stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionary_power_readings = {}

def update_dict():
    global dictionary_power_readings
    ApparentPower = "power"
    dictionary_power_readings[time.time()] = ApparentPower
    print(dictionary_power_readings)
    dictionary_power_readin
```

Comment: What doesn't make sense to me is that I can update the variable using the line "dictionary_power_readings[time.time()] = ApparentPower" but cant set it to blank.  Why is that?

Comment: You can't just use time.time() because it's float not int. Try this
`dictionary_power_readings[int(time.time())] = ApparentPower`

Answer (score 0):

Use Global keyword in your function

```
def update_dict():
     global dictionary_power_readings
     ApparentPower = "power"
     dictionary_power_readings[time.time()] = ApparentPower
     print(dictionary_power_readings)
     dictionary_power_readings ={}
```

It works , just try it once